# How to use CSS to create a particular stylized, multi-lined text box?

Tags: html, css

I have the task of using CSS to create a stylized text box that looks like this:

[image: desired stylized green multi-line text region]

I've been the server developer for many sites and occasionally do jump in to CSS, and usually figure things out in a reasonably clean way.  However, I'm really stuck with this one - it's been an hours-long drag slowly working my way through things, to begin to get this going.

I have not yet begun the colorizing or borders.  For now, I'm stuck trying to position the first line of text *vertically*.  I would rather not force the **height** or **width** of any of the lines of text, as this seems to me to risk breaking if text/size is slightly changed.

Instead, I'd rather use semantics such as **centering** and **vertical-align: top;** (etc) (at least partially).

The green colorization is optional for this question.  I'm much more concerned about the positioning of the text.  Also, please don't be concerned about the choice of font (I'll hopefully be able to figure that out myself) - but font SIZE (and bolding) is important.

The current state of my attempted CSS is shown below - which doesn't work.  My current CSS (below) leaves the image on the page looking like this:

[image: bad CSS attempt]

(The blue colorization is just Chrome Web Developer highlighting, which I've provided to indicate the size of the `div` that includes the text of the first line.  The actual background color is white.)

In the above image, I have not begun worrying about the colorization or borders.  The current status of the above image is that I'm just trying to get the text *"CLICK HERE for a"* to appear at the TOP of its div - as noted, WITHOUT setting the height or width of the `div` to "collapse" onto the text, if possible.

My current trouble positioning the *"CLICK HERE for a"* text vertically is just one issue I've been dealing with.  I would like to have a complete, working sample of the text and text positioning for this image, done "the right way" (or at least done in not a bad way).  Perhaps the *right* way really is to set the **width** and **height** of the `click-here-for-a` `div` (see CSS below) to be nearly equal to the text dimensions, in order to force its `absolute` positioning (but as noted, I'd rather not unless answers here correct me, by telling me that this is a good way to do it).

Here is the HTML / CSS for the above (incorrect) image:

HTML:

```
<div class="smooth-click-region">
    <div class="click-here-for-a">
        CLICK HERE for a
    </div>
    <div class="intro-offer-on-home-delivery">
        <div class="intro-offer">Special Introductory Offer</div>
        <div class="on-home-delivery">on Home Delivery</div>
    </div>
    <div class="discount-description">2 weeks @ 30% off - as low as $78/week</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro-offer-smooth-click-region {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 258px;
    height: 61px;
}

.click-here-for-a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

.intro-offer-on-home-delivery {
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro-offer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.on-home-delivery {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.discount-description {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 9pt;
    height: 12px;
}
```

What is the right way to use CSS to create the image above - at least in terms of text formatting and positioning?

Comment: You are using too much position: absolute; in your css. You just need 3 elements, 2 p and one h3 :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9zaa1v1/2/ Solved, more or less.

Comment: @TylerH Why are you using so many divs??? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitis

Comment: I deeply appreciate everybody's responses - if a C++ or PHP question ever arises, I hope to return the favor.  @TylerH, among all of the excellent answers for which I'm grateful, yours is the one I'd like to use.  If you would post it as an answer, I can award it.  Thank you again for your help to all who responded.

Comment: Note to others who may land here: Also check that some outer element (not shown in this question) does not set `line-height` (in my case, an outer element was setting `line-height: 2em;`, which was ruining my attempts to get this working before I even posted the question).  Frankly, I probably would have gotten it without posting this question if it weren't for the enclosing element setting `line-height`.  Alas.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski The common practice is to provide a solution to OP's question that changes as little as possible. Five divs instead of one w/ paragraphs and spans is not a noticeable change in code efficiency or speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer at your request. It helps to add `span` tags around single lines of text that you want to style independently.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y9zaa1v1/2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="smooth-click-region">
    <div class="click-here-for-a">
        <span>CLICK HERE</span> for a
    </div>
    <div class="intro-offer-on-home-delivery">
        <div class="intro-offer">Special Introductory Offer</div>
        <div class="on-home-delivery">on Home Delivery</div>
    </div>
    <div class="discount-description">2 weeks @ 30% off - as low as $78/week</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.smooth-click-region {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 258px;
    height: 61px;
    background: #cebd44;
    border: inset 1px dotted;
    border-style: double;
}

.click-here-for-a span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.click-here-for-a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

.intro-offer-on-home-delivery {
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.intro-offer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.on-home-delivery {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.discount-description {
    font-size: 9pt;
    height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, as simple as it gets http://jsfiddle.net/1dmhLm9c/

```
.smooth-click-region{
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}
p, h2{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

You can style it as you want :)

Comment: This uses stylistic HTML tags, which are deprecated. It's also green for some reason... (and it also doesn't have the border OP requested)

Comment: For an example is perfect, and why not green :)

Comment: @Paulie_D Note that box shadow is not calculated in the width and height of the element and if the element's size is sensitive in the document flow it will cause issues.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Not green because the user had a color in the OP and it was not green.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some site with a similar boxes that works well and inspect it with firebug. That will show you the html layout.. You can get some good ideas for how you want to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7xtf1f8m/

CSS:

```
.smooth-click-region {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #aa6;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #cc0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.smooth-click-region span {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.inner {
    padding: 0.3em 3em;
    background-color: #aa6;
}
.click-here-for-a {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.intro-offer-on-home-delivery {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.discount-description {
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="smooth-click-region">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="click-here-for-a"><span>CLICK HERE</span> for a</div>
        <div class="intro-offer-on-home-delivery">
            Special Introductory Offer<br/>
            on Home Delivery
        </div>
        <div class="discount-description">2 weeks @ 30% off - as low as $78/week</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the multiple borders by using the CSS3 `box-shadow` property. HTML tags have by default some CSS attributes so you do not have to define them in your CSS. For example the tag `<div>` is a block level element and by default has `display: block;` (you defined it for `div.click-here-for-a`).

You do not have to write too much unnecessary css.
This is my example for you:

```css
.smooth-click-region {
    background:#acb014;
    width:260px;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #FFF,0 0 0 10px #acb014;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth-click-region">
    <div class="click-here-for-a">
        CLICK HERE for a
    </div>
    <div class="intro-offer-on-home-delivery">
        <div class="intro-offer"><strong>Special Introductory Offer</strong></div>
        <div class="on-home-delivery"><strong>on Home Delivery</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="discount-description">2 weeks @ 30% off - as low as $78/week</div>
</div>
```

I did not changed your html code but I advise you to use other HTML tags that have their default css. Use h1, h2, h3 for headlines and p for paragraphs, etc.